# use gsp import in scaffolding templates

Tags: templates, grails, import, gsp, scaffold

Does anybody know, how to escape an import like below in scaffolding templates? I want to use this import in my generated views.

```
<%@ page import="nl.ihomer.enums.Status" %>
```

Comment: What do you mean by escape an import?

Comment: Best I could do was find [an ancient JIRA](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-833) and you can see how Grails does the top `page import` in [the source](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-crud/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/scaffolding/DefaultGrailsTemplateGenerator.groovy#L219)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couldn't escape an import in scaffolding templates, because the domain is in the different package. You could 
replace "Status" to "nl.ihomer.enums.Status" where you use the domain if you must escape an import. Hope that it could help you!